# Use a custom query when generating CSV in Activeadmin

Tags: csv, activeadmin

I have additional calculation columns (based on joins) I want to include in my CSV.

If I open and calculate it individually for every record

```
csv do
  column :complicated_calculation {  |r| r.calculate_things }
end
```

it's going to take a long time to generate with thousands of records.

I need to customize the `SELECT` query for when my CSV is generated and then use the columns in that query. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

[Customizing resource retrieval](http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#customizing-resource-retrieval), in documentation, shows you how without rewriting the whole csv builder: modifying `scoped_collection`.

So if you have your query nicely waiting in your model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_calculation
    select("people.*, (mumbo + jumbo * fumbo) "\
      "AS complicated_calculation") # notice we name the attribute here
    .joins("LEFT JOIN games ON person_id = people.id")
    .group("people.id")
  end
end
```

with your calculation you can do:

```
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      super.with_calculation
    end
  end
```

and then your CSV will have the attribute for free:

```
csv do
  column :complicated_calculation
end
```

Comment: That is will be change the data list on index action. That is possible to only custom csv download action ?

Comment: @Jonathan.Allard is there a way to not to affect the `index table` with the `scoped_collection` customization for CSV?